# Breeze doesn't populate collection navigation property

Tags: javascript, breeze, entity-framework-6

I've got an Entity Framework 6, database-first, model that I am querying behind a BreezeController.  My problem is when I query the controller for the object, breeze does not populate the navigation collection property.  It's defined, but it's empty.

Here's the server-side (generated) POCO and Breeze controller method:

```
public partial class Inventory
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<InstrumentReading> InstrumentReadings { get; set; }
}

public partial class InstrumentReading
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public Nullable<int> InventoryId { get; set; }
}

[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    ....
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Inventory> Inventories([FromUri] int id)
    {
        var data = _repository.Inventories(id);
        return data;
    }
}
```

And this is what I'm doing to query it in javascript:

```
        return EntityQuery.from('Inventories')
            .expand('InstrumentReadings') 
            .withParameters({ id: id })
            .toType('Inventory').using(self.manager)
            .execute().then(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {

            var entity = data.results[0];
            self.log('Retrieved [' + entityName + '] id ' + entity.id
                + ' from remote data source', entity, true);
            return entity;
        }
```

If I look at the response to the controller call in FireBug, everything is there, including a populated navigation property:

[image]

But why can't breeze populate the collection navigation property?

When I look at the metadata store, everything looks good from what I can tell:

[image]

I'd really hate to have to do a separate round trip to query the InstrumentReadings after I retrieve an Inventory.  I thought breeze was supposed to do that for me.

Thanks for any assistance!
Corey.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `expand` query method to [eager load](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples#EagerLoading) the InstrumentReadings.

```
return EntityQuery.from('Inventories')
    .expand('InstrumentReadings')  // <-- include the instrument readings
    .withParameters({ id: id })
    .using(self.manager)
    .execute()
    .then(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It seemed logical, but it did not make any difference.  Updated the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at other posts and I reviewed how the foreign keys were defined in thie child entity.  Turns out there were 3 other foreign keys on the entity which appeared to confuse EF and Breeze.  When I refactored the child entity to include a single navigation property, everything started working.